# How to setup SSH Jump Server that forwards SSH connection to client?

Tags: ssh, networking, vps

I have:

- VPS with dedicated IP address, e.g. 77.100.100.100. It has SSH server on port 22.

  - Inside it, it has a running Docker container.

    - Inside a Docker container, there is Wireguard server.
    - A client. It is connected to Wireguard server, which runs inside Docker container, whose host is VPS. The client has SSH server on port 22000 and has IP 10.13.13.8 in Wireguard container's local network.

So the scheme is:

```
           VPS               ->   Wireguard Docker container
(77.100.100.100, SSH on :20)            (10.13.13.1)
                                              ^
                                              |
 I want to          ->        client is connected (13.13.13.8, SSH exposed on :22000)
connect to it
  by SSH
```

I want to setup SSH Jump Server.

How can I connect by SSH from some machine to VPS's ip address and access the client? What should I setup exactly?